# Highcharts, datetime, xAxis label. How to show all dates on x axis, not only even dates?

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I'm new with Highcharts and stuck with a question. I need to display all dates on x axis, but by default, I'm supposing, only even dates are displaying. How can I display all dates?
[image]

Here my code:

```
const options: Options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
        },
        xAxis: {
            crosshair: false,
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'Days',
            },
            labels: {
                format: LABEL_FORMAT[period],
                rotation: 90,
                align: 'left',
            },
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Values',
            },
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'test',
                type: 'column',
                data: [
                    [1651363200000, 10],
                    [1651449600000, 15],
                    [1651536000000, 5],
                    ...
                ],
            },
            {
                name: 'test 2',
                type: 'column',
                data: [
                    [1651363200000, 10],
                    [1651449600000, 20],
                    [1651536000000, 30],
                    ...
                ],
            },
        ],
       },
    };
```

This chart is not only used for to display day, but also for months and years.
Please, answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `xAxis.tickInterval` option. In this case:

```
  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
      rotation: 90,
      align: 'left'
    },
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t0Lohusx/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

Comment: Thanks for your response, your solution works, but it works only for to display  days. As I wrote before, my chart is not only used for to display days, but also for months and years. I found more suitable solution for my case,  "tickPixelInterval: null" works for me. If tickInterval is null this option sets the approximate pixel interval of the tick marks and all tick marks are displaying. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPixelInterval